# Yearly & Behavioural Appraisal Database / Table Strucutre

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am developing a custom HR site for our companys internal software requirements and the management wants to have a function where they will evaluvate an employee yearly and monthly

Which are Yearly & Behavioural Appraisals

So for this i am wondering how to struture a table for this functonality.

In terms of table structure, The Behavioural Appraisals are 10 which are all the same for every one working in the company.

But for Yearly Appraisals each employee gets evaluvated under different topics which change employee to employee

For the moment I have created a form for inputting the values by their superviors as below,

[image: Screen For Inputting Feedbacks From Supervisors]

[image: Behavioursal Appraisal]

As for the Behavioural Appraisal for now I have created a sepereate table which has a struture like below,

[image: Table For Behavioural Appraisals]

I am wondering how can i acheive the yearly appraisal, mainly curious on the fact if we alter the table and create columns inside the table without specifying a specific employee we will end up with a huge load of columns and empty column values since every employee is evaluvated under different topics

Comment: I think rather than having `B1, B2 .. etc.` columns, why don't you just have 1 `Behaviour` (or `Behaviour_id`) and 1 `Score` (?) column and store each behaviour records by row.

Comment: @fadlikidd I have made the strucutre like that because the behavioural topics are all the same for every employee and those wont be changed. So, I thought to store all data in a single table and fetch the data by employee id and have certain limitation by not allowing more than 2 records per year to be inserted

Comment: @fadlikidd the issue is with the annual appraisal where each employees are evaluvated on different topics and i am wondering how to store and fetch data for those

Comment: No. Store the behavioural details in a separate table (employee and month (or test_id), behaviour_attribute, score). Store annual appraisals in a separate table (or tables).